# What exactly does "[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS..." mean

Tags: html, reactjs, socket.io

Does anyone know what it is? Because it is rather annoying, and I don't want it to cause problems later on in my application. I'm working with React, and it's running on port 5000. I'm making an online chat-application using socket.io etc.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs console error (\[HMR\] Waiting for update signal from WDS...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59695102/reactjs-console-error-hmr-waiting-for-update-signal-from-wds)

Answer (score 7):

That message is intended for development process and it is just there to notify you that your server is running in dev mode and it is awaiting changes you make so it can refresh the browser. HMR is acronym for [Hot Module Replacement](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/).

Try and stop your server in your console and you will see message:

> The development server has disconnected.
> Refresh the page if necessary.

You will not have any problems with this notification

Answer (score 5):

- *HMR* stands for [*H*ot *Module* *Replacement*](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/)
- *WDS* stand for [*W*ebpack *D*evelopment *S*erver](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)

It's a functionality only active in the development that can replace javascript code and css while the app is running. It helps you see changes to code reflected immediately in the app without having to reload the entire tab.