# Login through AAD (Azure Active Directory) in React app doesn't working

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-ad-msal, react-aad-msal

I'm trying to implement an authentication through Azure Active Directory for React app.
When I run my application, after login I get a blank page.
In the console I see:
"[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS..."

This is my provider:

```
export const authProvider = new MsalAuthProvider(
    {
        auth: {
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
            clientId: "********-****-****-****-************",
            postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
            redirectUri: window.location.origin,
            knownAuthorities: [],
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
        },
    },
    {
        scopes: [
            'user.read',
            'api://********-****-****-****-************/Read'
        ]
    },
{
        loginType: LoginType.Redirect,
        tokenRefreshUri: window.location.origin + '/auth.html'
    }
);
```

package: react-aad-msal

In Azure: I have an app registeration, with SPA platform. Redirect URI: http://localhost:3000.

Anyone has ideas?
I tried many things, and read about it but with no result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue seems to be more related to the react not related to Azure AD authentication. Did you get a chance to look at the [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59695102/reactjs-console-error-hmr-waiting-for-update-signal-from-wds).?

Comment: Hi, I had some problems. The main solution was to change 'common' to my tenat id, and to define aad to be single tenant.
Thank you for your reply

Comment: Glad to know you found the solution. Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 0):

(Moving from comments to answer so that others may more easily find it)

The issue is resolved for the customer by changing the authority URL from **Common** to specifying single **TenantID**.